# os.rename module appears to delete files in output directory

Tags: python-2.7

I have this code project I'm working on where `mp3s` are copied from one directory to another, and then renamed with a `random 4 letter string`.  I can get the files to copy to the output directory, but `os.rename` appears to delete the files.

```
for c in dirContents:
    print str(c)
    filepath = os.path.join(outDir, c)
    if (os.path.isfile(filepath)):
        random = ''.join([choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for n in xrange(4)])
        os.rename(filepath, random + '.mp3')
```

is there something I'm missing in the rename function?

Answer (score 0):

If the output folder already has a file with the same name, os.rename will not overwrite this file, just simple "do nothing". Therefore, this file is appear to be deleted. Maybe that's your case.